# How to build a wrapper function for querying database using dbplyr and dplyr, having the query vary

Tags: r, dplyr, eval, rlang, dbplyr

I'm trying to build a wrapper function for querying an SQL database using `{dplyr}` and `{dbplyr}`. It is always the same database, accessed via the same connection. The only thing that varies is the query.

Let's use an example based on code from Hadley's book [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta-big-picture.html#eval-funs):

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)

mtcars_db %>%
  filter(cyl > 2) %>%
  select(mpg:hp) %>%
  head(10) %>%
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110
#>  2  21       6  160    110
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Alternatively, we might have wanted a different query, such as to get the `min()` value for several columns (e.g., `mpg`, `disp`, and `drat`).

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)

mtcars_db %>%
  summarise(min_mpg = min(mpg), min_disp = min(disp), min_drat = min(drat)) %>%
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   min_mpg min_disp min_drat
#>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    10.4     71.1     2.76
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

So given the structure above (mtcars_db -> "query" -> collect()) I want to build a wrapper function `get_data_from_db()` that could flexibly accept different queries.

**My unsuccessful attempt**

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

get_data_from_db <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  if (kind_of_query == "from_hadley_book") {
    my_query <-
      rlang::expr(
        filter(cyl > 2) %>%
          select(mpg:hp) %>%
          head(10)
      )
  }
  
  if (kind_of_query == "mins_for_mpg_disp_drat") {
    my_query <- 
      rlang::expr(
      summarise(min_mpg = min(mpg), min_disp = min(disp), min_drat = min(drat))
      )
  }
  
  mtcars_db %>%
    eval(my_query) %>%
    collect()
}

get_data_from_db("from_hadley_book")
#> Error in eval(., my_query): invalid 'envir' argument of type 'language'
get_data_from_db("mins_for_mpg_disp_drat")
#> Error in eval(., my_query): invalid 'envir' argument of type 'language'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

I just gave it a shot using `rlang::expr()` and then `eval()`, but this strategy might be incorrect in general for solving this problem. Would be happy to learn how to fix `get_data_from_db()` using any relevant approach.

---

**EDIT**

---

I'd like to ask about another scenario in the same context of this question.

Let's take `get_data_from_db()` and its argument `kind_of_query`. What if I wanted greater flexibility in what I pass to `kind_of_query`, such that I could pass the *chain of dplyr verbs* to the argument?

That is, instead of `get_data_from_db("from_hadley_book")` how could I do `get_data_from_db(kind_of_query = filter(cyl > 2) %>% select(mpg:hp) %>% head(10))`?

Basically it means that `get_data_from_db()` is just a wrapper that "sandwiches" `mtcars_db` and `collect()` around the query passed via `kind_of_query` argument.

So this "flexible" version of `get_data_from_db()` would look like:

```r
get_data_from_db <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  mtcars_db %>%
    eval(kind_of_query) %>%
    collect()
}

## calling the function
get_data_from_db(kind_of_query = 
                   filter(cyl > 2) %>% 
                   select(mpg:hp) %>% 
                   head(10)
                 )
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at sqldf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html?

Comment: @DavidJ.Bosak, I've seen sqldf before, but I'm not sure how this package helps to answer the question.

Comment: It connects to a dataframe or SQLite database and you can pass in any SQL statement as a string and have the results returned dynamically.  It already does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidJ.Bosak,, I see, but I want to use `dplyr` verbs to compose the query, not SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Waldi hits on the crux of the problem, which is the pipe expects a function not an expression as the rhs. In the specific/choose from a list case, you control the expression building so this is manageable. You can use `magrittr` semantics and the dot placeholder to build from `kind_of_query`. This in turn can be used to create the complete expression (`query`) with `rlang::quo` and the `!!` operator.

```
get_data_from_db <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con))
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  if (kind_of_query == "from_hadley_book") {
    my_query <-
      rlang::expr(
        {
            filter(., cyl > 2) %>%
            select(mpg:hp) %>%
            head(10)
        }
      )
  }
  
  if (kind_of_query == "mins_for_mpg_disp_drat") {
    my_query <- 
      rlang::expr(
        {summarise(., min_mpg = min(mpg), min_disp = min(disp), min_drat = min(drat))}
      )
  }
  
  query <- quo(
    mtcars_db %>%  
      !!my_query %>%
      collect()
  )
  
  eval_tidy(query)
  
}
```

This is actually an overly sophisticated approach. If you're writing the expression for the `kind_of_query`, you might as well just simplify it by writing a function.

```
get_data_from_db2 <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con))
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  if (kind_of_query == "from_hadley_book") {
    my_fx <- function(x){
      x %>% 
        filter(cyl > 2) %>%
        select(mpg:hp) %>%
        head(10)
    }
  }
  
  if (kind_of_query == "mins_for_mpg_disp_drat") {
    my_fx <- function(x){
      summarise(x, min_mpg = min(mpg), min_disp = min(disp), min_drat = min(drat))
    }
  }
  
    mtcars_db %>%  
      my_fx %>%
      collect()
    
}
```

The problem comes with the general case. In the current proposed interface, you are trying to inject an argument value into a user-defined expression. The `!!` operator forces evaluation so when building the new expression, the user expression is inserted within `()` to force its evaluation before anything is passed from the lhs of the pipe. Manipulating the expression then likely requires `deparse` as suggested by @Waldi or some low level manipulation of the abstract syntax tree.

The simpler solution, if possible, would be to have your users pass in a function, similar to `purrr::map` or `lapply`. This would drastically simplify the function implementation

```
get_data_from_db_general <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con))
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)

  mtcars_db %>%
    kind_of_query %>%
    collect()
}

get_data_from_db_general(
  kind_of_query = function(x){
    x %>%
      filter(cyl > 2) %>%
      select(mpg:hp) %>%
      head(10)
  }
)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110
 2  21       6  160    110
 3  22.8     4  108     93
 4  21.4     6  258    110
 5  18.7     8  360    175
 6  18.1     6  225    105
 7  14.3     8  360    245
 8  24.4     4  147.    62
 9  22.8     4  141.    95
10  19.2     6  168.   123
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for discussing the issue from different perspectives. Isn't `get_data_from_db_general()` what is [called a ***functional***](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html)?

Comment: Yep, sure is :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the goal of the question is to avoid repeating `mtcars_db` and `collect()` steps in `mtcars_db -> "query" -> collect()` process for two different conditions. Since only `query` part is changing between the two conditions we need to change only that. Now `mtcars_db` and `collect()` stages are just examples and they can contain multiple steps in themselves which are common for both the queries.

My answer doesn't answer the question in a way which OP wants but if I had to do this I would do it in this way. The common stages can be saved in a variable which can then be used in `if` based on the condition passed.

```
get_data_from_db <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  common_piped_data <- mtcars_db
  if (kind_of_query == "from_hadley_book") {
    my_query <- common_piped_data %>% filter(cyl > 2) %>%  select(mpg:hp) %>%  head(10)
      
  }
  
  if (kind_of_query == "mins_for_mpg_disp_drat") {
    my_query <- common_piped_data %>% 
                  summarise(min_mpg = min(mpg), min_disp = min(disp), min_drat = min(drat))
  }
  my_query %>% collect()

}
```

Running the function -

```
get_data_from_db("from_hadley_book")
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6 160     110
# 2  21       6 160     110
# 3  22.8     4 108      93
# 4  21.4     6 258     110
# 5  18.7     8 360     175
# 6  18.1     6 225     105
# 7  14.3     8 360     245
# 8  24.4     4 146.7    62
# 9  22.8     4 140.8    95
#10  19.2     6 167.6   123

get_data_from_db("mins_for_mpg_disp_drat")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  min_mpg min_disp min_drat
#    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1    10.4     71.1     2.76
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe operator  `%>%` expects a function, whose first argument is the objet to be piped, see [introducing magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html). You provide an expression instead of a function, this explains the error message.

To be able to provide a literal `dplyr` query, you could `deparse` the input expression, build the `pipe` as a string, and `parse` it back: :

```
get_data_from_db <- function(kind_of_query) {
  
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), filename = ":memory:")
  mtcars_db <- dplyr::copy_to(con, mtcars)
  
  query <- deparse(substitute(kind_of_query))
  
  expr <- paste("mtcars_db %>%", query,"%>% collect()")
  eval(parse(text=expr))
}

## calling the function
get_data_from_db(kind_of_query = 
                   filter(cyl > 2) %>% 
                   select(mpg:hp) %>% 
                   head(10)
)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110
 2  21       6  160    110
 3  22.8     4  108     93
 4  21.4     6  258    110
 5  18.7     8  360    175
 6  18.1     6  225    105
 7  14.3     8  360    245
 8  24.4     4  147.    62
 9  22.8     4  141.    95
10  19.2     6  168.   123
```

This should fulfill your needs on this specific case, keeping in mind that parsing is usually not the recommended solution :

```
fortunes::fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```